# Android Studio - Parse Json into Singleton doesn't work

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments, singleton

I'm trying to parse some Json String into a singleton class "UserModel", so all my fragments can access to it.

I don't have any problem filling my "UserModel".
For exemple, I have an attribute class "Infos infos" in "UserModel" that get filled when I do

```
user = gson.fromJson(infos, UserModel.class);
```

That thing works perfectly, I can access "user.infos.*myAttributes*".

The problem is when I switch fragment, the "infos" class in my UserModel doesn't exist anymore, it's null when I want to access to it.

The weird thing is that, when I simply try adding a String in "UserModel", and modifying it, the string keeps the changing when changing fragment.
So I guess that the problem appear when I do that Json parsing.

-- EDIT --
Here is a part of UserModel, the singleton class:

```
public class UserModel {
    public static final UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
    public String token;
    public Infos infos;

    public static UserModel getInstance() {
        Log.d("UserModel", "GetInstance");
        return userModel;
    }

    public static class Infos {
        public String id;
        public String login;
    }
}
```

I have that in each fragment so I can access everywhere:

```
private UserModel user;
```

Here is how I instantiate it:

```
user = UserModel.getInstance();
```

Comment: Could you show more code? UserModel class and its initialisation in Fragment could be nice for starters.

Comment: Here what you asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of your UserModel written as proper thread-safe Singleton:

```java
public class UserModel {
    public static UserModel _instance;
    public String token;
    public Infos infos;

    public static UserModel getInstance() {
        if (_instance == null) {
            synchronized (UserModel.class) {
                if (_instance == null) {
                    _instance = new UserModel();
                    _instance.infos = new Infos();
                }
            }
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public static class Infos {
       public String id;
       public String login;
    }
}
```

Note, that your singleton class might be destroyed when you switch Fragments (for example when you replace one with another).

The safest solution would be instantiating your singleton in global Application class, thus making sure it will live until your app is terminated.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I didn't answer !

Comment: Great! Happy I could help then :)